# Problem with foreach loop with group by one column but have multiple values another column in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql, group-by

db_table => commitment

| ref_no | comm_date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-10-05 |
| 2 | 2022-10-05 |
| 3 | 2022-10-06 |
| 4 | 2022-10-07 |
| 5 | 2022-10-07 |
| 6 | 2022-10-08 |

db_table => collection

| ref_no | amount | trnx_date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 500 | 2022-10-05 |
| 2 | 100 | 2022-10-05 |
| 1 | 700 | 2022-10-06 |
| 3 | 400 | 2022-10-07 |
| 3 | 600 | 2022-10-08 |
| 5 | 800 | 2022-10-08 |
| 1 | 700 | 2022-10-08 |

I want to achieve something like this in datatable:

| ref_no | comm_date | collection summary |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-10-05 | 500 (2022-10-05) + 700 (2022-10-06) + 700 (2022-10-08) = 1900 |
| 2 | 2022-10-05 | 100 (2022-10-05) = 100 |
| 3 | 2022-10-06 | 400 (2022-10-07) + 600 (2022-10-08) = 1000 |
| 4 | 2022-10-07 | 0 |
| 5 | 2022-10-07 | 800 (2022-10-08) = 800 |
| 6 | 2022-10-08 | 0 |

How can I achieve this with php and mysql and show it to datatable. Thanks in advance!
What I have tried in sql in codeigniter model:

```
SELECT c.*, t.* 
FROM commitment c 
LEFT JOIN collection t ON c.ref_no = t.ref_no
WHERE c.ref_no IN (SELECT ref_no FROM collection)
GROUP BY c.ref_no
```

In controller:

```
public function collection_statement_list() {
         
    // Datatables Variables
    $draw = intval($this->input->get("draw"));
    $start = intval($this->input->get("start"));
    $length = intval($this->input->get("length"));
    
    $fetch = $this->Project_model->get_collection_statement();
    $data = array();

    foreach($fetch->result() as $r) {
      $ref_no = $r->ref_no;
      $comm_date = $this->Project_model->set_date_format($r->comm_date);
      $coll_date = $this->Project_model->set_date_format($r->trnx_date);
      
      
      $coll_summary = $r->amount.'<span class="text-primary"><small>('.$coll_date.')</small></span>';
            
      $data[] = array(
        $ref_no,
        $comm_date,
        $coll_summary,
      );
    }

    $output = array(
      "draw" => $draw,
      "recordsTotal" => $fetch->num_rows(),
      "recordsFiltered" => $fetch->num_rows(),
      "data" => $data
    );
    echo json_encode($output);
    exit();
  }
```

And the output in datatable is:
| ref_no | comm_date  | collection summary |
| ------ | ---------- | ------------------ |
| 1      | 2022-10-05 | 500 (2022-10-05)   |
| 2      | 2022-10-05 | 100 (2022-10-05)   |
| 3      | 2022-10-06 | 400 (2022-10-07)   |
| 4      | 2022-10-07 | 0                  |
| 5      | 2022-10-07 | 800 (2022-10-08)   |
| 6      | 2022-10-08 | 0                  |

Comment: what have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Can we have some existing code please, for context? See also [ask]. Thanks.

Comment: Something involving GROUP_CONCAT might be what you're looking for - see https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group_concat/ for examples.

Comment: As you code to show us that you would have tried...? I know it's possible to do that with PHP and MySQL. What I don't know is if possible only with MySQL.

Comment: Finally I searched and found. We can do it in SQL only with group_concat. Well done @ADyson

Comment: Sorry! Now I update the question with what I have tried so far. Please check now @ADyson

Comment: Thanks @ADyson. mysql_group_concat did the job just fine. Ur quick response is appreciated and sorry for unorganized question!!

Comment: That's great. You should add your solution below for others to learn from as well - and it can earn you upvotes of course :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And so in SQL only this query corresponds to your solution with group_concat...? I'm trying to answer to help those who would be looking for the solution in SQL only.

```
select COM.ref_no, 
if(COL.ref_no is not null,group_concat(COL.trnx_date,' (',COL.amount,')' separator '+'),'') as 'collection summary details',
if(COL.ref_no is not null,sum(COL.amount),0) as 'collection summary'
from commitment as COM 
left join collection as COL on COM.ref_no=COL.ref_no 
group by COM.ref_no
```

Answer (score 0):

I think such way. Imagine you have a table about amounts. It is will be solution by sql:

```sql
Select ref_no, comm_date, sub(summary) as collect_summary from amount;
```

However you may use alternative way to be group with php such:

```php
    <?php
    
    $amount = [
        ['ref_no'=> 1, 'amount'=>500 , 'date'=>'2022-10-05'],
        ['ref_no'=> 2, 'amount'=>100 , 'date'=>'2022-10-05'],
        ['ref_no'=> 1, 'amount'=>700 , 'date'=>'2022-10-05'],
        ['ref_no'=> 3, 'amount'=>400 , 'date'=>'2022-10-05'],
        ['ref_no'=> 3, 'amount'=>600 , 'date'=>'2022-10-05'],
        ['ref_no'=> 5, 'amount'=>800 , 'date'=>'2022-10-05'],
        ['ref_no'=> 1, 'amount'=>700 , 'date'=>'2022-10-05'],   
    ];
    
    $result = [];
    
    foreach($amount as $item) {
        $ref = $item['ref_no'];
        if(isset($result[$ref])) {
            $result[$ref]['collect_amount'] = $result[$ref]['collect_amount'] + $item['amount'];
            
        }else{
            $result[$ref] = [
                'ref_no' => $ref,
                'date' => $item['date'],
                'collect_amount' =>$item['amount']
            ];
        }
    }
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($result);
```